# Polymer strange looking Roboto rendering

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, templates, polymer

I've just tried using Polymer for the first time today, after hearing all the hype about it. It's awesome, but I seem to be getting some strange looking text, particularly on the headings:

[image: View Three]

[image: List]

It seems that that just the bold text is rendering strangely, as the others look just as you'd expect any Roboto text to look like.

I'd really appreciate anyone's help with this.

Comment: It might be [fake bolding](http://nimbupani.com/fake-bolding-of-web-fonts.html). Are you sure you have Roboto Bold as a webfont or installed on your machine?

Comment: Your screenshots don't look like Roboto to me (for either font weight). Have you confirmed in DevTools that the headings are actually using Roboto?

Comment: Thanks for the replies guys, I checked WhatFont (great chrome extension for fonts) and it definitely is Roboto. I went and installed all of the Roboto weights onto my machine, and the bold text is looking perfect. Looks like it's a problem within polymer that the bold weight isn't being pulled in. Thanks!